# How can I transform or copy an array to a linked list?

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-structures, arrays, linked-list

I need to copy an array to a linked list OR transform the array in a linked list.

How this can be done in .NET (C# or VB)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Depending on what version we're taking about here, you can :

```
LinkedList<YourObjectType> ListOfObjects=new LinkedList<YourObjectType>(YourObjectArray);
```

Answer (score 10):

To go to LinkedList from array:

```
var array = GetMyArray();
LinkedList<MyType> list = new LinkedList<MyType>(array);
```

To go to array from LinkedList:

```
var array = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net v2.0 or above:

```
Object[] myArray = new Object[] { 1, "Hello", 2, 3.0 };
LinkedList<Object> linkedList = new LinkedList<Object>(myArray);
```

You can replace `Object` with the type of element that the array actually holds.